# why the image color changed

Tags: asp.net, image, browser, colors

I made a picture with background-color `#005caa` in Photoshop .
When I use this image in my asp.net web site , the image color changed to `#034FFD` .
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bZCxx/) you can see , I upload this image and compare with color `#005caa` .
You can download and see my original color . But in browser , It's always show color `#034FFD`. I want to know why ? It's my browser issues ? I use Firefox 21.0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when the color in images "change" when viewed in a browser it's because they are saved in an color profile which the browser doesn't support.

Short answer: change the color profile of your image to RGB, don't use CMYK for the web.

[image: how to change color profile]
Here's an image to show you that you're using CMYK, while you should use RGB.

EDIT: 
it has nothing to do with "web safe colors". HTML supports a full 24bit color space. You have already proven this by putting a div with the right color in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell Photoshop to work with "original" web colors, this is a known issue. Take a look at this post, you can change the settings: http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/quick-tip-accurate-web-colors-in-photoshop/