# Image uploader changes image colour

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-processing, webforms

When we upload images through our image uploader, it changes the image colours to be very dull. I have been researching this online and came across a couple of articles about the images colour profiles and [why the image color changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229560/why-the-image-color-changed) on stack overflow.

The issue is that we believed the above reason was why it was not uploaded correctly, but when we uploaded the original image other platforms to test, like ebay, google drive and other places with image uploaders, it is uploading as per original.

Is there a setting I need to add to the code which will keep the correct image colour? I have attached a screenshot of the 2 images along side each other, the one on the left is the original, the one on the right is the one uploaded through our image uploader, the uploader is coded into our asp.net webforms project.

[image]

Comment: Some code or which libraries you used would be great to see. Without any code, its hard to help you. Configuration or manipulation of the image is the first thing I would have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel (the Original Poster) contacted me by email as they are making use of [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for the client-side file upload code.

While jQuery File Upload does not manipulate images, it can be used together with [JavaScript Load Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) or any other client-side or server-side image manipulation library.

I think your assumption is correct that the issue has to do with color profiles. Likely, the image is using an ICC profile (commonly used by PhotoShop), which is currently not supported by [JavaScript Load Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image).

A related issue is also discussed in this Github issue:
https://github.com/lovell/icc/issues/1

A possible solution would be to disable client-side image resizing, which is controlled in jQuery File Upload with the following option:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#disableimageresize

If client-side image resizing is already disabled, the issue lies with your server-side image manipulation library.
In that case, either switch to a library with support for the color profile used in your image or disable image manipulation.